# How to make a method in Android that executes every millisecond for a game?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an Android game that executes `gamelogic()` every millisecond. This is what I have tried.

```
long time = 0;
long previousTime = 0;
while (true) {
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (time - previousTime >= 1) {
        previousTime = time;
        gameLogic();
    }

}
```

The problem with this is that the while loop locks up the entire app
and the `gamelogic()` method is never executed. Thanks.

Comment: every milli-second is a bit over the top, try every 100 milliseconds?  BTW are you sure that `gameLogic` never gets executed (even once)?  Try chucking in some debug statements

Comment: It probably takes a few milliseconds to call System time and do the maths against the previous time.

Comment: you can use Thread.sleep(milisecounds); //mil and you need implement try catch

Answer (score 2):

Try [java.util.Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

```
 scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to execute the game update loop continuously.

It is useless to try to fire it every millisecond if it takes 2 milliseconds to run, you'll just add overhead.

And, as well, it is a waste to run it every 100 milliseconds if it takes 20 to run.

What I've done for things like this is to have a thread with a while loop, measuring how long each executing took.

It is essentially the same as the code you posted but passing an elapsedMilis param to the method gameLogic

```
long previousTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (gameIsRunning) {
   long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long elapsedTime = previousTime - time;
   gameLogic(elapsedTime);
   previousTime = time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Thread -> In this thread run:

```
while(true){
    gamelogic();
    try {
         thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Maybe this works

Answer (score -1):

there are multiple choices for you

you can use 1)[runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) or 2)[asynctasnk](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
for ai 
  or 3)you can call gameLogic() in ondraw if you are using canvas

```
 Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do what you wanna do.

        }
    });
```